# Memoization not working properly, python code from MIT Open Courseware "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming" Lecture 21

Tags: python, python-2.7, memoization, python-3.8

I'm brand new to coding and I'm working through the MIT Open Courseware 6.00 course "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming."  Lecture 21 covers dynamic programming and memoization specifically.

The assignment/lecture code is an optimization program, finding the combination of items with greatest value one can take from a set of items that will fit in a bag with limited capacity.  This is a section of the code that was provided:

```
def solve(toConsider, avail):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    if toConsider == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (0, ())
    elif toConsider[0].getWeight() > avail:
        result = solve(toConsider[1:], avail)
    else:
        nextItem = toConsider[0]
        #Explore left branch
        withVal, withToTake = solve(toConsider[1:],
                                    avail - nextItem.getWeight())
        withVal += nextItem.getValue()
        #Explore right branch
        withoutVal, withoutToTake = solve(toConsider[1:], avail)
        #Choose better branch
        if withVal > withoutVal:
            result = (withVal, withToTake + (nextItem,))
        else:
            result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
    return result

def fastSolve(toConsider, avail, memo = None):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    if memo == None:
        #Initialize for first invocation
        memo = {}
    if (len(toConsider), avail) in memo:
        #Use solution found earlier
        result = memo[(len(toConsider), avail)]
        return result
    elif toConsider == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (0, ())
    elif toConsider[0].getWeight() > avail:
        #Lop off first item in toConsider and solve
        result = fastSolve(toConsider[1:], avail, memo)
    else:
        item = toConsider[0]
        #Consider taking first item
        withVal, withToTake = fastSolve(toConsider[1:],
                                        avail - item.getWeight(),
                                        memo)
        withVal += item.getValue()
        #Consider not taking first item
        withoutVal, withoutToTake = fastSolve(toConsider[1:],
                                              avail, memo)
        #Choose better alternative
        if withVal > withoutVal:
            result = (withVal, withToTake + (item,))
        else:
            result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
    #Update memo
    memo[(len(toConsider), avail)] = result
    return result

import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

def test(maxVal = 10, maxWeight = 10, runSlowly = False):
    random.seed(0)
    global numCalls
    capacity = 8*maxWeight
    print '#items, #num taken, Value, Solver, #calls, time'
    for numItems in (4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024):
        Items = buildManyItems(numItems, maxVal, maxWeight)
        if runSlowly:
            tests = (fastSolve, solve)
        else:
            tests = (fastSolve,)
        for func in tests:
            numCalls = 0
            startTime = time.time()
            val, toTake = func(Items, capacity)
            elapsed = time.time() - startTime
            funcName = func.__name__
            print numItems, len(toTake), val, funcName, numCalls, elapsed
```

In the lecture, when the instructor runs this test code there is a drastic difference in the performance of fastSolve due to the use of memoization, but when I run this code the memoization doesn't appear to be working - there is no difference in the number of calls or run time between Solve and fastSolve.

I understand this code was written for an earlier version of python (2.7 I believe) and I'm currently using python 3.8.0.

Can anyone help me to identify why fastSolve/memoization isn't working as expected?

Comment: I don't see how `(len(toConsider), avail)` could possibly be a usable key for your memo.  Are *all* situations with five (for example) items remaining to take exactly equivalent, no matter what the values of those five items are?

Comment: @jasonharper in the test case, yes - I am using a set list of item objects, so in all cases where there are n items remaining in the list, each of those items have the same value.

admittedly, this doesn't seem like a super useful example - but it was created for teaching purposes, as an example where memoization can be applied.  I just can't get it to execute correctly and no matter how many times I review it, it looks like it should be working.